# Image Capture of chart in iPhone is bigger than that from iPad

Tags: ios, iphone, uiimage, core-plot

We are using following code to save png image from iPhone/iPad to media library but the size is bigger then the iPad.

we are using coreplot to generate chart. To save an image using imageofLayer from cptGraph.

```
CPTGraph *gp = self.hostView.hostedGraph;
self.hostView.bounds = CGRectMake(0,0,640,480);
gp.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, 640, 480);
graph.title = txtChartTitle.text;

UIImage *newImage=[gp imageOfLayer ];
NSData *imgData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(newImage);
UIImage* im2 = [UIImage imageWithData:imgData];
CGRect cropRect = CGRectMake(0.0 ,0.0 , 640.0, 480.0);
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(cropRect.size, YES, 0.0);

[im2 drawInRect:cropRect];
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

[UIPasteboard generalPasteboard].image = im2;

if([self diskSpace]>[imgData length])
{
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(im2, self,@selector(image:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:),nil);

}
else
{

    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@""
                                                    message:@"The chart cannot be saved due to insufficient storage space available."
                                                   delegate:nil
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                          otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
    alert=NULL;
}
```

Comment: If you want a lossy format use jpeg.

Comment: Do both devices have Retina screens? Devices with retina screens will make images with double the resolution...

Comment: What size is the image on each platform?

Comment: Thanks jjv360 you are right. for Retina screens it showing double size of image.for non retina screens it is showing size 640x480 and for retina it is showing 1280x960.